# Importance of "this"

Tags: java, c++, this, cocos2d-x

i'm programming in c++ using cocos2dx and when adding a sprite or objects,

this-> `addChild(something)` and `addChild(something)`

works. Both ways come up with same result.

But not only in `c++`, *`this`* is used in android programming too (perhaps, all programming languages use "this"?). I've used this in Java to replace ClassName.class, with simple *`this`*. But besides this purpose *`this`* is used in many ways.

But because I haven't gone deep into programming languages, I don't know if they really do the same job (this-> `addChild` vs. `addChild` AND `ClassName.class` vs. `this`).

Why do we need *`this`*?

.

.

Self Answer:

*`this`* is a keyword that refers to the current class instance or object in many object-oriented programming languages.

so...just for comfort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` has a few uses. First, in some cases, you will need to explicitly refer to the receiver object in the current method, perhaps if you're passing it as a parameter to another function. For example, consider this C++ code:

```
void someOtherFunction(SomeClass* arg);

void SomeClass::doSomething() {
    someOtherFunction(this);
}
```

Here, `someOtherFunction` is a free function that takes a pointer to a `SomeClass` object. The only way to call it in the context of `doSomething` so that the receiver object is the parameter is to use `this`.

`this` in C++ is also used in assignment operators, which need to return a reference to the receiver object:

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator= (MyClass rhs) {
    // Do something to the receiver object
    return *this;
}
```

Here, `return *this;` means "return a reference to the receiver object," which couldn't be expressed without `this`.

`this` is also used to disambiguate in a few circumstances. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int value;

    public MyClass(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Here, the use of `this` in the `MyClass` constructor is to differentiate between the parameter `value` and the field `value`. Referring to `value` by itself selects the parameter, while using `this.value` refers to the field.

Hope this helps!

Comment: second example is really new to me. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

consider also a normal type of constructor or setter

```
public ConstrcutMe (String name, int age)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public void setName (String name) {
{
   this.name = name;
}
```

I believe this fully illustrate why we need `this`

Comment: Actually it doesn't show why you need `this` - generally, although it shows `this` being useful *in Java*. A language could simply *forbid* shadowing (why not?) or use a different syntax to assign to member variables (like Ruby does). The only "universal" case I can argue for `this` is when *explicitly needing to refer to the current instance*, such as when using in an external method call.

Answer (score 2):

Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using `this`.

**Usage in Java:**

Here is given the 6 usage of `this` keyword.

1. `this` keyword can be used to refer current class instance variable.
2. `this()` can be used to invoke current class constructor.
3. `this` keyword can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly)
4. `this` can be passed as an argument in the method call.
5. `this` can be passed as argument in the constructor call.
6. `this` keyword can also be used to return the current class instance.

Let's consider a problem:

```
class student
{  
    int id;  
    String name;  

    student(int id,String name)
    {  
        id = id;  
        name = name;  
    }  
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println(id+" "+name);
    }  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        student s1 = new student(1,"NameA");  
        student s2 = new student(2,"NameB");  
        s1.display();  
        s2.display();  
    }  
}
```

Output will be:

```
0 null
0 null
```

Solution for the problem:

```
class Student
{  
    int id;  
    String name;  
    student(int id,String name)
    {  
        this.id = id;  
        this.name = name;  
    }  
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println(id+" "+name);
    }  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        Student s1 = new Student(1,"NameA");  
        Student s2 = new Student(2,"NameB");  
        s1.display();  
        s2.display();  
    }  
}
```

Output will be:

```
1 NameA
2 NameB
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `this` is a keyword which evaluates to a pointer to the object the method is being called on.

Strictly for convenience, the compiler can figure out, in some cases, where you want to call another method on the same object. If the object has a `fooBar` method, then you can write it as `this->fooBar();`, or for convenience you can write just `fooBar();` and the compiler will understand it as `this->fooBar();`.

However, in other cases you really do need to use `this` explicitly. Consider if you want the method to return the instance itself. You have to refer to the instance itself somehow, which you can do using `return this;`. Or, if you want to call another function, say `barMan`, passing in the instance itself - again you need to use `this`: `barMan(this);`.

Comment: Why?  Some idiot ;)  Your reply is perfectly correct.  As you already know :)

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword (or an equivalent such as `self` in Python) is a mechanism to "refer to the instance upon which the executing method has been invoked", although the meaning can var across languages and contexts. This - hah! - is thus trivially handy when needing to "pass the current instance" from within a given method.

In addition, some languages *require* that `this` (or other expression which evaluates to an instance) is manually specified when invoking a member; that is, `this` must always be specified: `this.m()`. Other languages allow an ["implicit receiver"](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~budd/Books/oopintro3e/info/slides/chap05/slide06.htm) meaning that `this.m()` and `m()` are equivalent, where `m` is a member function associated with the current instance.

Likewise, the use of `Type.m()` usually denotes a call to a "static method" defined on a type; once again, this is language-specific, and some languages support first-class type values, in which no method is truly "static".

There is no particular rhyme or reason other than it is how a *particular* language has been defined - and questions should be focused on a *specific* context in a *specific* language<sup>1</sup>. For most every reason I can give for one language, I can give a counter-example in a different "OOP" language.

---

<sup>1</sup> Case in point: you refer to `ClassName.class`, however, in Java this is just special syntax to obtain the corresponding `Class` object and has *nothing* to do with `this` or members (static or not).

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword, as you correctly stated, is used to refer to the current instance of a given class.

It's very common to see the `this` keyword in object-oriented languages like C++ and Java (which is used for Android development), as it can make code easier to read and more uniform. Non-object oriented languages tend not to have it, although I'm sure you could find one that does.

My favorite example is constructors and instance variables. If you a class `Ducky` and a instance variable `String duckName`, it makes sense for the constructor to look something like this:

```
public Ducky(String duckName)
{
  this.duckName = duckName;
}
```

This way, you can use clear variable names in more than one context without confusing yourself and/or future maintainers of your code.